# Hoy to export @expr data table to sheets in google app maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have one table in google app maker. The table has  two numbers and one result and the values are binded as follows:

number1 = `@datasource.item.number1`

number2 = `@datasource.item.number`2

result = `@datasource.item.number1+@datasource.item.number2`

When I export the data to sheets, app maker export only number1 and number2. I don't Know how I can to export result to sheets?

I am using AMU function to export data.

Comment: Since you are using the AMU library, perhaps you should reach out to them to see if they can assist with that.